# Python regular expression. Find a sentence in a sentence

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to find an expression "K others" in a sentence "Chris and 34K others"

I tried with regular expression, but it doesn't work :(

```
import re


value = "Chris and 34K others"

m = re.search("(.K.others.)", value)

if m:
    print "it is true"
else:
    print "it is not"
```

Comment: Use `(K.others)` for regex?

Comment: `re.match()` vs `re.search()`?..

Comment: re.search() I need to find a subsentence "K others"

Comment: Your regex is looking for one more character following "others", which your value string does not have.

Comment: The fundamental confusion appears to be that you don't know what `.` does.  It matches a single character which is not a newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that you're web-page scraping "*you and 34k others liked this on Facebook*", and you're wrapping "K others" in a capture group, I'll jump straight to how to get the number:

```
import re

value = "Chris and 34K others blah blah"

# regex describes
# a leading space, one or more characters (to catch punctuation)
# , and optional space, trailing 'K others' in any capitalisation
m = re.search("\s(\w+?)\s*K others", value, re.IGNORECASE)

if m:
    captured_values = m.groups()
    print "Number of others:", captured_values[0], "K"
else:
    print "it is not"
```

[Try this code on repl.it](https://repl.it/D2ke/4)

This should also cover uppercase/lowercase K, numbers with commas (1,100K people), spaces between the number and the K, and work if there's text after 'others' or if there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match something *within* the string, use `re.search`. `re.match` starts at the beginning, Also, change your RegEx to: `(K.others)`, the last `.` ruins the RegEx as there is nothing after, and the first `.` matches any character before. I removed those:

```
>>> bool(re.search("(K.others)", "Chris and 34K others"))
True
```

The RegEx `(K.others)` matches:

```
Chris and 34K others
            ^^^^^^^^
```

Opposed to `(.K.others.)`, which matches nothing. You can use `(.K.others)` as well, which matches the character before:

```
Chris and 34K others
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, you can use `\s` to escape space and match only whitespace characters: `(K\sothers)`. This will literally match K, a whitespace character, and others.

Now, if you want to match all preceding and all following, try: `(.+)?(K\sothers)(\s.+)?`. Here's a link to [repl.it](https://repl.it/D2mD/1). You can get the number with [this](https://repl.it/D2mD/2).

Comment: but this is also true Chris and 34Mds others f. I need that there will be "<something>K others<it can be something> I tried this but it is still not perfect m = re.search('.K others$|.', like)

Comment: You can use `(K\sothers)` @AnnaK which will match only `K others`.

Comment: Thank you :) could you write me please how to define that it can be something after sothers ? (K\sothers\.|$) that it match "hhdsd 34K others a" but also "hhdsd 34K others" Thank you :)

Comment: @AnnaK Do you mean something like this: `(.+)?(K\sothers)(\s.+)?`. First group will get `Chris and 34`, second will get `K others` and third will get `<stuff after others here>`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `search` rather than `match` unless you expect your regular expression to match at the beginning. The help string for `re.match` mentions that the pattern is applied at the start of the string.

Comment: The last `.` in your pattern does not match anything in your test string.